Looking for a way to change or remove a registry key owned by NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller using either Pwsh 7 or C#
I am creating a Windows App dedicated to context menu customization. I am going to use a combination of Powershell 7 and C#. There are default keys created during an installation of Windows 10 or 11 that I want my application to be able to remove if the user chooses. This requires me to be able to delete or change a registry key that is owned by NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller from an application that is only running in Admin context.
I am looking for a way to accomplish this using both Powershell 7, and C#. I need implementations for both languages since I'm testing things out first in Powershell before I create the final code in C#.
So, essentially:
How can I take ownership and then delete/modify keys owned by TrustedInstaller from:

A powershell 7 script running as Admin
A C# application running as Admin

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions.

I'm not sure I understand what you're stuck on. You've given some options for what you want to do, and imply that they don't work, but you haven't said how so.

I don't understand your confusion. I need an implementation (code) to remove or modify a windows registry key owned by TrustedInstaller from an application running in Admin context. Using either C# or Powershell. I haven't tried anything yet except use a third party tool to elevate a command. I don't want to depend on a third party tool for my application. So I need code.

Please choose either C# or PowerShell. How you perform this task will depend on the language. It sounds like you're going to start with PowerShell. Questions involving multiple languages are generally Too Broad. I'll ask again, what are you stuck on? An internet search shows a number of different posts on this topic.

@gunr2171 I found a C# implementation from someone in the Powershell discord that grants your application "TakeOwnership" privileges, so that's a good start. I think I have enough to go own now between the implementation I was given and the answers in the duplicate SO post.

@user246821 I'm not asking someone to write an entire application for me, I'm asking for a specific implementation of a method that is likely very common. There are plenty of questions on this site asking for code to run with, let's be realistic here.
